# Is multiple assignment of tuples slower than multiple assignment statements?

Tags: scala, syntax, microbenchmark

Is there a difference between assigning multiple variables using a tuple, and assigning them in multiple statements?

For example, is there a difference between the following code snippets?

```
// multiple assignment using tuples
val (x, y) = (str.length, str.substring(1, 2))

// multiple-statement assignment
val x = str.length
val y = str.substring(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

There *is* a difference. The approach of using tuples is actually invoking an extractor (the `unapply` method), which would incur a cost at runtime. The second approach is certainly faster.

To get an idea about the difference, here is a decompilation of two methods showing both approaches. You can see clearly how the first approach causes much more operations.

An important point to note here is that the first expression requires auto-boxing to a `java.lang.Integer` (because `Tuple2` accepts objects), while the second expression uses the value without boxing.

```
  public void m1(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: new           #16                 // class scala/Tuple2
       3: dup           
       4: aload_1       
       5: invokevirtual #22                 // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
       8: invokestatic  #28                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
      11: aload_1       
      12: iconst_1      
      13: iconst_2      
      14: invokevirtual #32                 // Method java/lang/String.substring:(II)Ljava/lang/String;
      17: invokespecial #35                 // Method scala/Tuple2."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      20: astore_3      
      21: aload_3       
      22: ifnull        75
      25: aload_3       
      26: invokevirtual #38                 // Method scala/Tuple2._1$mcI$sp:()I
      29: istore        4
      31: aload_3       
      32: invokevirtual #42                 // Method scala/Tuple2._2:()Ljava/lang/Object;
      35: checkcast     #18                 // class java/lang/String
      38: astore        5
      40: new           #16                 // class scala/Tuple2
      43: dup           
      44: iload         4
      46: invokestatic  #28                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
      49: aload         5
      51: invokespecial #35                 // Method scala/Tuple2."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      54: astore        6
      56: aload         6
      58: astore_2      
      59: aload_2       
      60: invokevirtual #38                 // Method scala/Tuple2._1$mcI$sp:()I
      63: istore        7
      65: aload_2       
      66: invokevirtual #42                 // Method scala/Tuple2._2:()Ljava/lang/Object;
      69: checkcast     #18                 // class java/lang/String
      72: astore        8
      74: return        
      75: new           #44                 // class scala/MatchError
      78: dup           
      79: aload_3       
      80: invokespecial #47                 // Method scala/MatchError."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      83: athrow        

  public void m2(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: aload_1       
       1: invokevirtual #22                 // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
       4: istore_2      
       5: aload_1       
       6: iconst_1      
       7: iconst_2      
       8: invokevirtual #32                 // Method java/lang/String.substring:(II)Ljava/lang/String;
      11: astore_3      
      12: return        
}
```

Comment: Byte code does not tell the whole story. You'd have to see what the JVM optimizer does with that thing. It might very well be able to optimize it away entirely. It is not that hard: the Scala.js optimizer can do it, so I wouldn't be surprised if the JVM did it too.

Comment: @sjrd Thanks for your note. The JVM can probably optimize part of it. After 10000 invocations of that line, it should be able to get rid of the `throw` instruction, and maybe the cast too. Note, however, that I didn't mention that there was a performance difference; I'd have to measure it to say that. I'm just pointing out the difference from a theoretical perspective, helping people to better understand how Scala works, uncovering something that the compiler hides from us.

Comment: Sorry, I said that I didn't mention performance, but I actually did. Actually, I don't think the JVM can optimize the whole expression. Scala.js should be able to do that during the compilation phase. But since the Scala compiler didn't do that, I don't think the JVM would omit instructions that are allocating objects and boxing values. Kindly check my update regarding boxing.

Comment: The Scala.js optimizer does it at link stage, with whole program knowledge, and without special knowledge about tuples or anything (only fairly standard optimizations). In theory, the JVM has all the necessary information. With optimizations such as inlining and scalar replacement (which the JVM does), the whole thing can be eliminated (even boxes, since they do not escape the method after inlining). But, yes, again, that's the theory. I'm not saying the JVM actually eliminates it; just saying it *can*.